# angularjs directive with ng-repeat not respecting = scope binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive with an isolated scope with two properties. One of them set to data-binding with the equal sign. If I manually insert the directive several times the html document, changes to the values are reflected, as expected, on the scope in the controller. But if I insert the elements with a repeater (ng-repeat) the connection to the scope on the controller no longer works. Any idea why?

The directive looks like this:

```
myApp.directive("phone", function(){
return{
    restrict: "E",
    scope:{
        number:"@",
        dirname:"="
    },
    template:  '<div class="panel"> <input type="text" ng-model="dirname"><br>Number:{{number}}  {{dirname}}</div> '

}

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll guess (since you didn't provide any HTML or model data) that you have an array of dirnames, so inside the ng-repeat, you are trying to bind the ng-model to a primitive.  Since each iteration of ng-repeat creates its own child scope, when you first type into a textbox, a `dirname` primitive property will be created on the child scope.  (This is how [JavaScript prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482) works.)

The fix is to use an object rather than a primitive.

```
$scope.names = [ {name: 'Superhero'}, {name: 'Julio'} ];

<li ng-repeat="nameObj in names">
   <phone number="123" dirname="nameObj.name"></phone>
</li>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/fSkX3/).

Comment: Actually dirname is a property that should be shared across all phone directives. But defining an object as you suggests did the trick thanks.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, under ng-repeat my directive is being called only once.